# ObjectiveC sqlite3 issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I'm finding that I have an issue when updating/inserting into my table in my iPhone app because I have a TEXT column, and when that text includes a ' symbol, things get messed up. What is the best way to handle this?

Should I check before I use a string that has an apostrophe? Is there a quick way to add formatting that will add an escape character in front of each apostrophe?

Does this question even make sense? lol.

Comment: It sounds like you're building a SQL query string yourself.  Don't do that.  Use a wrapper like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) instead, which will handle this for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sqlite requires the ' symbol to be escape by two ''.

Look at this from the [official sqlite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q4):

```
(14) How do I use a string literal that contains an embedded single-quote (') character?

The SQL standard specifies that single-quotes in strings are escaped by putting two single quotes in a row. SQL works like the Pascal programming language in the regard. SQLite follows this standard. Example:

    INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('5 O''clock');
```

Comment: is there a quick way to say "newString = oldString + double quotes where needed"

Comment: use:
newString=[oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];

Answer (score 5):

There's three ways to solve this:

1. Do the formatting yourself. **Don't do this.** (Well, not unless this string is part of your code rather than user input. In that case, this approach is fine.)
2. Use `sqlite3_mprintf("%Q")` to have SQLite do this. (`%q` does quote replacement; `%Q` does quote replacement and inserts NULL for a null pointer.)
3. Use bindings in your statement that you fill in with `sqlite3_bind_text`. This is the best way to do this, since it doesn't require recompiling the statement for every string and doesn't open you to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Using a binding would look like this:

```
sqlite3_prepare(db, "INSERT INTO Table(Column) VALUES(?);", -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                  -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
// stepping, etc
```

(Don't forget to do error checking.)

Comment: I believe you reversed the order of the last two arguments in sqlite3_prepare. I believe it should be `sqlite3_prepare(db, "INSERT INTO Table(Column) VALUES(?);", -1, &stmt, NULL);` +1 for the great solution.

Answer (score 5):

hey forget all this stuff. If you want your db to contain ' . Just replace your string with %27 & when fetching it back convert it back . You will get what you want. Check below :

```
// while Inserting into db
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"%27"];

// while fetching it back
        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%27" withString:@"'"];
```

Enjoy programming :) :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a function provided with SQLite that can escape characters as needed. Take a look at:
sqlite3_mprintf

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html