# Save json object in sqlite like text and retransform to dictionary on read

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite, nsdictionary

I want to save a Json Object in a field (text) sqlite and then read it again with a select and retransform to NSDictionary or NSMutableArray to parse the key/values

This is how i save actually in the sqlite DB

[image]

As you see, is a song object from the iTunes api. I want to read that object and parse it.

This is how i make the select query and save it in a NSDictionary while i filling and NSMutableArary

```
globals.arrayMyPlaylists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Form the query.
NSString *query = @"select * from myplaylists";

// Get the results.
NSArray *listas = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

for (int i = 0; i < listas.count; i++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSLog(@"lista %d %@ %@", i, listas[i][0], listas[i][1]);
    [dictionary setObject:listas[i][0] forKey:@"id"];
    [dictionary setObject:listas[i][1] forKey:@"nombre"];


    NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select cancion from canciones where idplaylist = %@", listas[i][0]];
    NSArray *canciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query2]];
    [dictionary setObject:canciones forKey:@"canciones"];



    [globals.arrayMyPlaylists addObject:dictionary];
    dictionary = nil;
}
```

When i try to read it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
NSArray *canciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[globals.arrayMyPlaylists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"canciones"]];
```

and try to get the value for the key artworkUrl100

```
[cell.tapa1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[canciones objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"artworkUrl100"]]] placeholderImage:nil];
```

i get the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7ff575810600> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key artworkUrl100.'
```

i understand i'm messing up in some way with dictionarys/nsmutablearrays. I need some help. Thanks!

EDIT: this is how i save the data in the DB

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into canciones (idplaylist, cancion) values ('%@', '%@')", [[globals.arrayMyPlaylists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"], self.elementoSeleccionado];
[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
```

self.elementoSeleccionado is the NSMutableArray with the "cancion" object and it's saved like it's shows the first image.

EDIT 2: this is what i get trying schmidt9's answer

[image]

EDIT 3: OK, i have the json string escaped. How i have to parse now?

[image]

Comment: It seems that you save the whole `cancion` simply as a string, without parsing it to a dictionary, you should parse it to a JSON object first

Comment: look, i edited the question responding on what you say

Comment: ok, you save one json object per row

Comment: yes, one json object (aka song) per row

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your output first with [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html):

```
NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select cancion from canciones where idplaylist = %@", listas[i][0]];
NSArray *canciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query2]];

// I suppose your array canciones should contain only one song object ...
NSError *error = nil;
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:canciones[0] options:0 error:&error];

if(error) { 
    // handle error ... 
}

if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSDictionary *result = object;
    [dictionary setObject:result forKey:@"canciones"];
}
```

**Edit**
Saving to database
2 options:
- if you get a prepared json string, save it directly to DB, but before you should escape quotes. See eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539486/objectivec-sqlite3-issue)
- if you have `NSDictionary`:

```
- (NSString*)JSONStringWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary prettyPrinted:(BOOL)prettyPrinted
{
    NSJSONWritingOptions options = (prettyPrinted) ? NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted : 0;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:options error:nil];
    return  [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

After that you should escape the string too.

Comment: look EDIT 2! i answer you there!

Comment: hm, concerning your screenshot you get 2 arrays wrapped one in another, basically immutable array -> mutable array -> json object ... Maybe you should try something like `canciones[0][0]` to get out the object and check output of my snippet, I have not tested it

Comment: Yes, i did that! NSData *data = canciones[i][0]; and then -> id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; Now i get another error, but i think because the data saved in db start with < and end with > (like <65875 8786476 96986875 758465 987986785>)

Comment: well, does not work. wich is the way i have to save the json object in db?

Comment: as far as I know "<>" are not escape characters in sqlite, that's why they cannot cause an error. Do you get your song to a dictionary?

Comment: Parse the same way

Comment: im getting error in this line: id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];